# How to take out strings from lists and compare them one character at a time

Tags: python, string, list, compare

I have two lists looking like:

> ```
> L1 = [[25, 34, 'ABCD', 'EFG']]
>
> L2 = [[12, 22, 'ABCD', 'EGH']]
> ```

I want to extract "ABCD" from both lists and compare them one character at a time.
To extract the strings from the lists I used:

> ```
> string1 = [string[3] for string in L1]
>
> string2 = [string[3] for string in L2]
> ```

To compare them I used: (Because I both want the character and position)

> ```
> if len(string1) == len(string2):
>
>     for i, char in enumerate(string1):
>         print(i)
>         print(char)
> ```

When printing I only get position 0 and for char I get the whole string (ABCD).
How should I do to get each position and get each character one at a time?

Comment: Add another [0]. So if your string1 = "ABCD" then string1[0] is A string1[1] is B

Comment: `if char == string2[i]: print('fell happy')`

Comment: for i in range(len(string1)): print ('i: %d, char: %s'%(i,string1[i]))

Comment: First of all, `str[3]` extracts the last element of the list and not `ABCD`.Then,`string1` is a list with only one element, that is why you get only one index and the `ABCD`. You can convert it to string by writing `enumerate(''.join(string1)):`. Also keep in mind that `str` is built-in function of Python and should not be used as variable.

Comment: str[3] was a bad example and I edited. Thanks for informing me. The `enumerate(''.join(string1))` worked, but now when I should compare the strings I used: `if string1[char] != string2[char]` and I get the error: `list indices must be integers or slices, not str`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using:

```
[string[3] for string in L1]
```

To get `"ABCD"` from `L1` will only get the last string, irregardless if it is `"ABCD"` or not. Just keep it simple at write a function that extracts this for you:

```
def extract(lst, ext):
    for l in lst:
        for string in l:
            if string == ext:
                return string
    return None
```

Which behaves accordingly:

```
L1 = [[25, 34, 'ABCD', 'EFG']]
L2 = [[12, 22, 'ABCD', 'EGH']]

str1 = extract(L1, "ABCD")
str2 = extract(L2, "ABCD")
fail = extract(L1, "ABC")

>>> print(str1)
"ABCD"
>>> print(str2)
"ABCD"
>>> print(fail)
None
```

Then just loop over both strings at once with [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip), once both strings have been checked to be valid:

```
if str1 and str2 and len(str1) == len(str2):
    for i, char in enumerate(zip(str1, str2)):
        print(i, char[0], char[1])
```

Which outputs:

```
0 A A
1 B B
2 C C
3 D D
```

Comment: Thanks now I get what I want. I really appreciate your very well described solution.

Comment: No problem. If you want to, give this answer a green tick if it was helpful, for future users.